# Will Blender charge me for exporting videos?

Tags: export, video, licensing

Almost every single app I've attempted to use wouldn't let me export my video by email or drive. They don't even let me put it on my desktop. I'm a student and a couple of my classes ask for videos. Will Blender make me pay to share my videos with my teachers?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question shows very little research and effort. Have you read the [official license](https://www.blender.org/about/license/)? Have you tried exporting a video and see what happens?

Comment: Every content created with blender is yours.

Answer (score 9):

No, Blender will not charge you.

Blender is an open source 3D development software that provides free access for anyone to do almost anything they want with it.

Even if it was, you will find that many programs will provide free student copies and accessibilities.

Taken from the licence page:

> This license grants people a number of freedoms:
>
> - You are free to use Blender, for any purpose
> - You are free to distribute Blender
> - You can study how Blender works and change it
> - You can distribute changed versions of Blender

The Majority of restrictions are for the source code and software distribution.

As @Duarte Farrajota Ramos said, you should take a look at the [licence](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) if you have any queries.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Answer (score -4):

I'm not an expert, but I've never been charged.  Saved them to a folder and emailed them to clients with no issues at all.